# Decimal Degrees in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-systems

Sup guys...

I'm looking for a problem that I think it's easy to resolve, but I just can't find the answer.

I'm developing a SaaS with OpenStreetLayers. I'm used to Google API, but I want to learn OSM.

How do I change my coordinate system to Decimal Degrees?
My coordinate system is showing something like this:-4363377.97 | -1756393.59 in OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition.
I can't "center" my map with Gmaps Latlon, like "center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-46.645203,-23.553917)"

This is my code:

```
    <div id="map" class="mapa"></div>
<script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;

function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Streets", 
                {numZoomLevels: 20}

            ),

        ],
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-23.553917, -46.645203)
                    ,zoom: 10,

    }
    );
 map.addControl(
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
                    div:document.getElementById("coor"),
                    prefix: 'EPSG:3857 coordinates:',
                    separator: ' | ',
                    numDigits: 2,
                    emptyString: 'Mouse fora do mapa.'

                })
            );
        /*  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition( {id: "coor", formatOutput: formatLonlats} ));
}
</script>
```

Please, give some light, and sorry about my english.

Thx you all...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from degree to decimal using transform and two projections:

```
  var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(projection1,projection2);
```

See: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html#OpenLayers.LonLat.transform

Usual projections are EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857.
There may be other ways...